# Firebase Cloud Messaging Silent Push Notification fail to work

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented firebase cloud messaging in my app and I wish to implement silent push notification.

I have done all the necessaries and send the following json post request to my app.

```
{
  "to": "/topics/news",
  "notification": {
    "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "body": "5 to 1"
  },
  "content_available": true,
  "priority": "normal"
}
```

The app successfully receives the notification when it is in background, but the notification is still displayed as banner (I believe silent notification means there will not be any badge, banner displaying right?)

Comment: How have you handled the notification in your code. The badge and banner are generated from the code after the notification is received by the device. So it depends on how UNUserNotificationCenter delegate method handles it.

Comment: @kapsym how about ios9? I think UNusernotificationCenter does not do it for ios9 right?

Comment: From iOS 9 point of view, payload looks fine. Still need the code for your didReceive completion handler to understand any issues from code side. Can you add a bit more code on how notification is handled.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your notifications to be silent, they have to contain only data payload, with no notification content. So, you should remove this:

```
"notification": {
"title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
"body": "5 to 1"
}
```

Review [message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) for more details.